# Is $L^1(0,T;V') \subset H^{-1}(0,T;H)$ for $V \subset H \subset V'$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bochner-spaces

My question is about a passage in the paper 'On the existence of the pressure for solutions of the variational Navier–Stokes equations' by J.Simon. (It can be found easily via Google). It says the following on page 4 and 5:

> We are now in position to check that, for such a right-hand side, it is not possible to associate a pressure to the velocity given by the weak equation in order to satisfy the Navier–Stokes equation.
>   Let us recall, for $d \leq 4$, an existence result of a weak solution given by J.–L. Lions in [5], see Theorem 6.1 p. 69, Corollary 6.2 and Footnote (2) p. 74 (see also [10], Theorem 3.1 p. 282 together with the equivalence of problems 3.1 and 3.2 stated p. 282). Given
>   $$f ∈L^2\big((0,T);V′\big), u_0  \in H$$
>   there exists
>   $$u ∈ L^2 \big((0, T ); V \big) ∩ L^\infty \big((0, T ); H \big) ∩ C \big([0, T ]; H_\text{weak}\big) \tag6$$
>   such that $u(0) = u_0$ and
>   $$⟨∂_t u − ν∆u + (u \cdot ∇)u, φ⟩_{H^{−1}(Ω)d×H_0^1(Ω)} = ⟨f, φ⟩_{V'×V}, ~∀φ ∈ V. \tag7$$ 
>   The terms in the left-hand side are defined in the following space: $$∂_t u∈H^{−1}\big((0,T);H\big), (u\cdot∇)u∈L^1\big((0,T);L^{4/3}(Ω)\big),
> ∆u ∈ L^2\big((0, T ); H^{−1}(Ω)\big).\tag8$$

I checked his reference [10] (Temam: Navier-Stokes Equations) which says that the weak time derivative of $u$ is in $L^1(0,T;V')$ and can be improved to $L^{4/3}(0,T;V')$ in three dimensions. Now I don't get how Simon can say that $\partial_t u \in H^{-1}(0,T;H)$. It seems like he is saying since $u\in L^2(0,T;H)$ that for the weak derivative one takes one step from $W^{0,2}(0,T;H)$ to $W^{-1,2}(0,T;H)$ - but this is kinda handwaving and seems not correct.

So, how to get from $L^1(0,T;V')$ to $H^{-1}(0,T;H)$?

Right, here the definition of the spaces:
$$H:=\{u \in L^2(\Omega)^d : \text{div} u=0, \gamma_\nu u =0 \}$$
$$V:=\{u \in H_0^1(\Omega)^d : \text{div} u=0 \}$$

EDIT: Posted my attempt as an answer for future reference if someone got a similar question.

Comment: I would say that this follows from $u \in L^\infty(0,T; H) \subset L^2(0,T;H)$.

Comment: @gerw Thank you for your comment. I get that $L^\infty(0,T;H) \subset L^2(0,T;H)$ but how do we get that $u' \in H^{-1}(0,T;H)$ from that?

Comment: Using integration by parts: $\langle u',v\rangle =\langle u,v'\rangle $.

Comment: @gerw Thank you, I pondered for some days, first I got frustrated but then I asked myself what I actually have to check. I edited my post; I'd be really grateful if you can look at it and tell me if this is what you intended.

Comment: Yes, this looks correct.

Comment: @gerw Thank you so much! Also for just hinting and not showing the full solution - I learned from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments for the hint of gerw. I did the following:

\begin{align} ||u'||_{H^{-1}(0,T;H)}&=\sup \frac{|\langle u', \phi \rangle_{H^{-1}(0,T;H),H_0^1(0,T;H)}|}{||\phi||_{H_0^1(0,T;H)}} \\ &=\sup \frac{|(u', \phi )_{L^2(0,T;H)}|}{||\phi||_{H_0^1(0,T;H)}} \\ &=\sup \frac{|(u, \phi' )_{L^2(0,T;H)}|}{||\phi||_{H_0^1(0,T;H)}} \\ &\leq\sup \frac{||u||_{L^2(0,T;H)} ||\phi||_{H_0^1(0,T;H)}}{||\phi||_{H_0^1(0,T;H)}} \\ &=||u||_{L^2(0,T;H)} \end{align}

where I used the Gelfand-Triple 
$$H_0^1(0,T;H) \hookrightarrow L^2(0,T;H) \hookrightarrow H^{-1}(0,T;H)$$